# After rejection magento extension version

Tags: extensions, package

I have created package extension for magento.My extension was rejected and also uploaded my_extension_name with version 1.0.0. Now I have solved all issue created proper guideline.Should I have upload again new higher version(e.g. 1.1.0) or older version 1.0.0 in for upload package in magento website ?

Comment: Hi, is your extesnion is live as i facing issues while testing the extesnion on my local machine before submitting

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217669/how-to-use-create-extension-package-in-magento-1-9?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload extension with the same version. You don't need to change the version.