# How to use Create Extension Package in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, packaging

I created a module now i want to make it live, for this, i am using `Create Extension Package` **and trying to install from connect manager before submitting for approval**

[image: inrsaurabh]

Issues that i am facing:

1) in `var/connect` i have

```
hb-pc-15@hb-pc-15:/var/www/html/magento-mirror/var/connect$ ls -la
total 1464
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data    4096 Mar 16 17:10 .
drwxrwxrwx 8 www-data www-data    4096 Mar 16 17:08 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data    6355 Mar 16 17:10 modulename.xml
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 1477013 Mar 16 17:10 Companyname_Modulename-1.0.0.tgz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data    2950 Mar 16 17:10 Companyname_Modulename.xml
```

2) In `Companyname_Modulename-1.0.0.tgz` i have

app
    ----> code
     ----->etc
skin
package.xml

**design folder is missing**

Update: i got the correct `Targets and Path`

[image: path]

**Update:** I am getting an error,

```
CONNECT ERROR: Unsupported resource type
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the folder path from,
`/frontend/base/default/modulename` to `frontend/base/default/modulename` and `/adminhtml/default/default/template/modulename` to `adminhtml/default/default/template/modulename`. Please refere here, https://www.brihaspatitech.com/blog/create-magento-extension-package-file/

Comment: sorry, check updated answer.

Comment: If this helpful for you means please accept the answer this will help for others

Comment: i tried by removing / still same output

Comment: please check those folder paths, may be you missed something

Comment: i got the issue

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: it was the `template`